# If $f$ is a periodic function with period $P$, then what we say about the periodicity of the function $f(mx+ny)$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions, periodic-functions

Can we speak about periodicity of multivariable function. It is periodic in the direction of $x$-axis only right?

Comment: Do you mean $h(x,y)  = f(mx+ny)$?  Why isn't that periodic in both $x$ and $y$?

Comment: U mean in all direction? What can we say about period?